# Injecting html dom inside iframe's document and/or shadow-root

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting iframe onto the webpage using javascript (using chrome extension). Using javascript, I am creating iframe and I can access my html's url, so I though I can fetch the DOM using `$.get`

```
var elt = document.createElement('iframe');
elt.id = 'my_iframe';

$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('views/test.html'), function(doc) {

    var container = document.querySelector('#my_iframe');

    console.log(container.documentContent);  // can access
    console.log(container.shadowRoot); // can't access

    // ideally:
    container.shadowRoot($(doc));
    container.contentDocument($(doc));

});

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elt);
```

[image]

How can I inject my 'text.html' inside the `#shadow-root`?

The reason is that, when I use `elt.src = url`, it doesn't wrap the html content inside `#document` or `#shadow-root`, and this results in a bug - (blurry content in iframe when not wrapped in `#document` or `#shadow-root` -  [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826646&q=bertugkorucu%40gmail.com&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified))

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen? do you want to set the content of an iframe through shadow-root? you can't shadow root is read-only

Comment: I can change injected `.html` too. The reason I need this is because when I use `iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('views/test.html');`, it doesn't make `#document` and `#shadow-root`, so it gets blurry for some reason. I need a way to put my content inside `#shadow-root`

Comment: When I use `elt.src = url;`  it doesn't wrap the iframe content inside `#document` or `#shadow-root`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just changing the contents of an iframe, you can do it by:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('#myIframe')
iframe.outerHTML = '<iframe></iframe>' // clears the iframe
iframe.contentDocument.open()
iframe.contentDocument.write(yourHTMLText)
iframe.contentDocument.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't put the external html inside the `#document` or `#shadow-root` though. Isn't this equivalent to `iframe.src = url`?

Comment: what do you need `shadow-root` for?

Comment: When the iframe content is not inside `#document` or `#shadow-root`, it gets blurry. [Here is my bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826646&q=bertugkorucu%40gmail.com&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: my answer does put the content inside the #document

Comment: I couldn't make this work. I tried with `container.contentDocument.write("<h1>Hello</h1>")` but no luck. It removes the existing iframe, and creates a new iframe, and don't put any content. Also get `content.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null` if empty`

Comment: the html text must be a valid html; with the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<head></head>`, and `<body></body>`

and also setting the outer html is necessary to clear previously loaded files on the iframe, if you are doing this repeatedly.

Comment: Made it work with your technique. It really solved the bug. Thanks